# Why I'm getting 404 Resource Not Found to my newly Azure OpenAI deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-openai

I've gone through this [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/quickstart?pivots=programming-language-studio) and I created my Azure OpenAI resource + created a model deployment which is in state succeedded. I also playaround it in https://oai.azure.com/ and it works there.

But, If I try to reach it from REST API is returns 404 Resource Not Found.
I defined the `api-key` header, and took the url and json from `Code View` -> `json` from inside the playground.

I'm executing

POST
https://raz-openai.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/raz-model-2/completions?api-version=2022-12-01
{
"prompt": "",
"max_tokens": 100
}
with api-key header

Am I missing another step?

Comment: At this time [tag:openai] is only for questions about OpenAI API. Ref. [Disambiguate \[chatgpt\] and \[openai\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422589/1595451). As Azure OpenAI is part of Azure Cognitive Services, it looks to be fair to use [tag:azure-cognitive-services] instead.

Comment: This eventually worked, I think I issue GET and not POST actually.

Comment: @RazRonen if the above solution worked for you, post it as an answer so that it will help other community members.

Comment: Can you post you request code?  Maybe remove "max_tokens" and use the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as an answer use a GET request instead of POST.

Answer (score 8):

I was also getting a 404 calling the Chat Completions API (https://{resource}.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/{deployment}/chat/completions) and it turned out that I was using the wrong version.  Each model has one or more versions that can be found at [Azure OpenAI Service REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/reference).

For me, hitting the chat completions (ChatGPT), the correct URL with version was:

**https://{resource}.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/{deployment}/chat/completions?api-version=2023-03-15-preview**

Any other version will give a 404 Resource Not Found.

Also, here are the definitions of those variables:

- Resource:  Take from the Azure endpoint URL, which can be found on the Overview page in your OpenAI Services resource.  The format should be something like https://{resource}.openai.azure.com/
- Deployment (aka deployment-id):  You can find this in the Azure portal under the Model Deployments section.  Each model has a "Model Deployment Name" and this is your Deployment ID.  This isn't going to be the OpenAI name (like gpt-35-turbo) but rather the name you gave it when creating the model deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Chrome web traffic (under Network) from the Azure OpenAI studio. It works better than the official docs and the Azure OpenAI Studio UI-generated code.